# Amazon s3 .NET SDK , the bucket you are trying to access must be addressed using specfied endpoint

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, amazon-s3

I am using amazon .NET SDK in widows phone 8 app for uploading images, the code was working fine.Now I get an exception

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

I have updated to latest version of SDK 2.0.2.2, Has anything changed with the update?

My code

```
string awsID = "myid";
    string secretKey = "mysecretkey";
    try{
   AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsID, secretKey,RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
     string s="";
     if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("selectedphoto1"))
     {

       s = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["selectedphoto1"] as string;
 }
     var InputStream = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("appname;component/Assets  /call.png", UriKind.Relative));
        var request = new PutObjectRequest()
        {
            BucketName = "mybucketname",

            ContentType="image/png",
           Key=s+".jpg",
           InputStream = myFileStream,
        };

        await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
 }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.InnerException);
    }
```

Comment: What is the innerexception of the TargetInvocationException set to?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have updated my question with exception details.

Comment: Did you set the `ServiceURL` on the `AmazonS3Config` you're passing in? Otherwise, how are you currently configuring it?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I ve added my code, no Im not passing amazons3config, and the code did work some days back..

Comment: Did you change the location of your bucket? It looks like your S3 client is configured for us-west-1 region.

Comment: @WadeMatveyenko I have a strange issue here when I change it to us-east-1 it works fine..Bt I have it in us-west-1 only.. it is evident from the URL of the image.. Any clues?

Comment: Same here with us-east-1, bug in API?

Answer (score 10):

This is happening because bucket region is incorrect.
Check your region on Amazon console at S3 bucket and configure the same in config file and code.

For example:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsID, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.APNortheast1);

<add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1" />
```